# How can we print a list of ASCII characters to the console, except forthose characters which have an escape sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ascii, non-ascii-characters

For any ascii characters `ch`, I would like to print `ch` unless `repr(ch)` begins with a back-slash character.

I want to print a list of all of the "*nice*" ascii characters.

#### Failed Attempt

```py
import re


characters = [chr(num) for num in range(256)]
# `characters` : a list such that every element
#                of the list is an ASCII character

escaped_chars = [repr(ch)[1:-1] for ch in characters]
# `escaped_chars`: a list of all ASCII character unless
#               the character is special
#               new line is stored as "\n"
#               carriage return is stored as "\r"

printables = "".join(filter(lambda s: s[0] != "\\", escaped_chars))

print("\n".join(re.findall('.{1,20}', "".join(printables))))
```

The console print-out is:

```py
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123
456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFG
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
]^_`abcdefghijklmnop
qrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦
§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»
¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏ
ÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâã
äåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷
øùúûüýþÿ
```

I seem to have printed a lot of weird unicode characters, such as `ç` and `õ`

Comment: Well, for one thing, values above 127 aren't ASCII characters.

Comment: The printable (official term for "nice") ASCII characters are between 32 (space) and 126 (~), inclusive.

Comment: [str.isprintable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable) might be useful.

Comment: @Thomas I consider tab characters to be not *nice* because `repr("\t")[0]` is a backslash, but tab characters (`"\t" == chr(9)`) are ***printable***, aren't they? All white-space characters can be printed to the screen, including line-feed (10), carriage-return (13), spaces (32), and tabs (9).

Comment: @sj95126 I see what I did now. Thank you. You're exactly right. I printed characters `0` through `255` inclusive. I should not have printed anything above `127`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters You can send any character to a terminal, but the definition of "printable" is that it just shows a glyph, without any special behaviour. All ASCII whitespace characters except space also have some other behaviour, including tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

characters = [chr(num) for num in range(127)]
# `characters` : a list such that every element
#                of the list is an ASCII character

escaped_chars = [repr(ch)[1:-1] for ch in characters]
# `escaped_chars`: a list of all ASCII character unless
#               the character is special
#               new line is stored as "\n"
#               carriage return is stored as "\r"

printables = "".join(filter(lambda s: s[0] != "\\", escaped_chars))

print("\n".join(re.findall('.{1,20}', "".join(printables))))
```

As [sj95126](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13843268/sj95126) wrote:

> values above 127 aren't ASCII characters

Here's right code

Comment: Note that `range()` always subtracts `1` from its upper limit. `range(127)` will visit the numbers from `0` to `126` inclusive, but not visit `127`. We missed a character. We want to write `range(128)` ... actually I might be wrong about that. feel free to correct me

Comment: 127 happens to be the DEL character, whose repr is `'\x7f'`, so in the end the output is correct – but I would still consider it a bug.